# Class is mapped despite igoring it with Fluent API

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to add a property of a type which shouldn't be mapped to the database model. Why does Fluent API's Ignore method have different behaviour than the NotMapped attribute? What is the actual equivalent of the NotMapped attribute?

I've read several posts and articles that claim that the actual equivalent to NotMapped attribute is the Ignore method. Unfortunately, if I don't add the mentioned attribute, I get the error:

> System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
>      at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowKeyNotFoundException()
>      at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
>      at System.Web.Http.OData.Builder.EdmTypeBuilder.ReorderDependentProperties(NavigationPropertyConfiguration navProperty)
>      at System.Web.Http.OData.Builder.EdmTypeBuilder.CreateNavigationProperty(EntityTypeConfiguration config)
>      at System.Web.Http.OData.Builder.EdmTypeBuilder.GetEdmTypes()
>   (...)

I want to avoid using any attributes on my domain model, so I'm trying to find a solution based on Fluent API.

Class 'Common.Model.SomeComplexModel' isn't a database entity.

```
public class Vehicle
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // An error occures if I remove following attribute
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.NotMapped]
    public Common.Model.SomeComplexModel AdditionalData { get; set; }
}
```

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   modelBuilder.Ignore<Common.Model.SomeComplexModel>();

   modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new VehicleConfiguration());
   (...)
}
```

```
internal class VehicleConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Vehicle>
{
    internal VehicleConfiguration()
    {
        (...)
        Ignore(v => v.AdditionalData);
    }
}
```